# Babel throws errors when trying to build react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs

Here is my error:

> Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel. (While processing preset: "C:\Users\ExpoTech\workspace\liability_release_form\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js");

I have tried over 6 suggested solutions from GitHub and Stack Overflow, but keep getting this same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "liability-waiver-release",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@trendmicro/react-toggle-switch": "^0.5.7",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "jshint": "^2.9.6",
    "jshint-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.8",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.7",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.5",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-modal": "^3.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.5",
    "reactstrap": "^6.5.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.12.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "start": "npm run build && node server/server.js",
    "build": "babel ./server/server.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "webpack": "^4.23.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
  }
}
```

Here is my .babelrc:

```js
{
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

Here is my server.js file:

```js
import express from 'express';
import router from './routes/routes.js';
import path from 'path';

const app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../client'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')));

app.use('/', router);

const port = 8080;

app.listen(port, function() {
 console.log('running at localhost: ' + port);
});

export default app;
```

Comment: This might help you with the issue https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8482#issuecomment-422923797

Comment: @Volodymyr - thank you, lol, I was just reading this and implementing it as I noticed your comment. I'm trying it now

Comment: The error you posted says "Inspect the stack trace of this error", but you've left that part out of the question. I can be a big help when tracking down issues like this, please include it if you can.

Answer (score 0):

While you are using these presets, you don't have them in your project.json file.

```
{
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

Update your package.json as follows.

```
{
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0", // remove this
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",  // remove this and install "@babel/env"
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "webpack": "^4.23.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
}
```

And install @babel/react.

Hope this helps. I have upgraded my project yesterday. :)